# Management of user data from Face Detection API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

My team has built an app that uses the Azure Face Detection API to upload a user's selfie and return some basic info. We POST this information to the West Europe server, as described on this page (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)

I need to understand what happens to the image data in terms of storage, retention, generated metadata, etc. - essentially all info around GDPR requirements. I understand from this page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-updates-cognitive-services-terms/) that "Cognitive Services customers own, and can manage and delete their customer data" but I cannot see where I can manage this data in the Azure console. I have also looked in the following places without luck:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/products
https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-gb/privacystatement

Can anyone show me where I can manage this data, or a privacy document outlining default behaviour around privacy please?

Thanks
Ferg